# Share lexical scope between successive eval statements in perl

Tags: perl, eval, lexical-scope

Can I make different snippets of `eval`ed Perl code share the same lexical scope and yet get their return values?

**Background**

Perl's eval command evaluates a string as Perl code and upon success returns the value of the last statement in that code. However, lexical variables created in that code are dropped at the end of the code. This means when eval of code1 has ended and I have a second code chunk code2, which refers to the lexical variables set in code1, this will fail.

```
my $code1 = 'my $c = 4';
my $code2 = 'printf "%g\n", $c;';

printf 'evaluated "%s" to %s' . "\n", $code1, eval $code1;
printf 'evaluated "%s"' . "\n", $code2;
```

yields

```
evaluated "my $c = 4" to 4
evaluated "printf "%g\n", $c;"
```

but not a line containing just `4` as I would wish, because `$code2` should use the variable `$c` if lexical scopes are re-used. (I generally agree with the default that lexical scopes are constrained to only one `eval`ed code, so I expect that some conscious modification of code is required to make the above work.)

**Approaches considered**

I experimented with `use PadWalker qw( peek_my );` to save the lexical scope at the end of each code snippet aiming to load it into the scope of the following snippet, but then I realised that this would make inaccessible the return value of the code snippet, which is needed by the calling code.

As another alternative appears to pattern-match (probably using a dedicated parser) all `my`-declarations in the perl code snippets and essentially translate them on the fly, but this would amount to a considerably bigger task.

**Template example for discussion (see comments)**

```
\perlExec{
    use PDL;
    my $v = vpdl [ 1, 2 ];
    my $w = vpdl [ 3, 4 ];
    sub list ($) {
            my $pdl = shift;
            return join ',', map { at( $pdl, $_, 0 ) } 0..1;
    }
}
The vector [ \perlValue{ list $v } ]
plus the vector [ \perlValue{ list $w } ]
makes [ \perlValue{ my $s = $v + $w; list $s } ].
```

Comment: I don't get why can't you move your lexical variables to outer scope? `{ my $c; ... ; eval $code1; eval $code2; }`

Comment: Why are you using `eval` in the first place, instead of two subroutines?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me. Why are you `eval`ing Perl code line-by-line?

Comment: Also, if you have control over the `eval`ed code, why use lexicals at all?

Comment: The code to be `eval`ed is read from configuration templates outside the application, so it will change much more frequently that the main perl code. It comes from different locations in the files. Perl is used in the files to automatically calculate values.

Comment: This is no problem. The problem arises when I try to re-use parts of calculations in one place to feed into calculations at another place later in the file to avoid repeating code. So I want to keep one lexical scope for each configuration file, which contains several Perl-fragments.

Comment: I still don't understand why you're compiling code at run time: why isn't your "config" an array of subroutines?

Comment: The templates are for texts, and I spend most time to write the text, so it must be easy to edit, structure and proofread also in the editor. I do not want perl syntax in places which do not require it.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could show a minimal example of such a configuration template which demonstrates the issue you described. My suspicion is that there is a different/better overall solution than "preserve lexicals across evals".

Comment: @haukex done, see edit above.

Comment: Thank you. Since at the moment I can't think of any good way to share lexicals across scopes, I am still wondering why you don't just use package variables instead, and `eval` the code in its own package so namespaces are not polluted. Another approach would be to translate your template into one big piece of Perl code to be `eval`ed, for example: `The vector [ \perlValue{ list $v } ]` becomes `print "The vector [ "; print list $v; print " ]\n"`.

Comment: I once wrote a really simplistic demo implementation of the latter option, [here](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1177887).

Comment: @haukex: `eval` the code in its own package sounds promising. How can I create a namespace and let the `eval`ed code refer to it (I guess with `our`)? I would consider dynamically creating an anonymous namespace to be used once more elegant, if possible, but see a workaround to manually wipe namespaces.

Comment: @haukex: translating the document to me does not seem an easy task. I believe the easy model you suggest would fail with `makes [ \perlValue{ my $s = $v + $w; list $s } ].` Just prefixing with `print` would not work, would it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you would like to use [Eval::WithLexicals](https://metacpan.org/pod/Eval::WithLexicals)? It does exactly what you are asking for. It was designed to power REPLs, and it's pure Perl. You simply make a new instance of `Eval::WithLexicals`, and then you call `$ewl->eval($code)` instead of `eval $code`, and the variables will persist between successive calls on the same object.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, my feeling was that this was an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) in that there may be other solutions to the underlying problem. As it turns out from the discussion in the comments, you seem to be implementing your own templating system, so my first suggestion would be to have a look at existing ones, such as maybe [`Template::Toolkit`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Toolkit).

If you still want to stick with your current approach, then it seems that @hobbs has given an answer that seems to answer your question directly, [`Eval::WithLexicals`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Eval::WithLexicals) (*Update:* since accepted). As I mentioned, I see two other possible solutions. The first, which feels the most natural to me personally, would be to not use lexicals in the fist place. When I see the code like what you showed:

```
\perlExec{ my $v = [ 1, 2 ]; }
The vector [ \perlValue{ $v } ]
```

then, simply because of the braces, I would not be surprised that each of those has their own lexical scope. If you instead were to use package variables, it would seem more natural to me. Just for example, you could use `eval qq{ package $packname; no strict "vars"; $code }` (of course with the caveat that `strict "vars"` is disabled), or your could use fully qualified variable names (`$package::v`) throughout.

The second thing I mentioned was to translate the *entire* input file into a Perl script and `eval` that - in other words, write your own templating system. Although I would **only** recommend reinventing this wheel as your **last** option, you did ask how to adapt [this code I wrote](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1177887) for your purposes, so here it is. One limitation of the following is that any braces in the code blocks must be balanced (*but see update below*), and since this is a somewhat simplistic demonstration, there are bound to be more limitations. Use at your own risk!

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say state/;
use Data::Dumper;
use Regexp::Common qw/balanced/;
use Capture::Tiny qw/capture_stdout/;
my $DEBUG = 1;

local $/=undef;
while (my $input = <>) {
    my $code = translate($ARGV,$input);
    $DEBUG and say ">>>>> Generated Code:\n", $code, "<<<<<";
    my ($output, $rv) = capture_stdout { eval $code };
    $rv or die "eval failed: ".($@//'unknown error');
    say ">>>>> Output:\n", $output, "<<<<<";
}

sub translate {
    my ($fn,$input) = @_;
    state $packcnt = 1;
    $fn =~ tr/A-Za-z0-9/_/cs;
    my $pack = "Generated".$packcnt++."_$fn";
    my $output = "{ package $pack;\n";
    $output.= "no warnings; no strict;\n";
    $output.= "#line 1 \"$pack\"\n";
    while ( $input=~m{ \G (?<str> .*? ) \\perl(?<type> Exec|Value )
                     (?<code> $RE{balanced}{-parens=>'{}'} ) }xsgc ) {
        my ($str,$type,$code) = @+{qw/str type code/};
        $output.= "print ".perlstr($str).";\n" if length($str);
        ($code) = $code=~/\A\s*\{(.*)\}\s*\z/s or die $code;
        $code .= ";" unless $code=~/;\s*\z/;
        $code = "print do { $code };" if $type eq 'Value';
        $output.= "$code\n";
    }
    my $str = substr $input, pos($input)//0;
    $output.= "print ".perlstr($str).";\n" if length($str);
    $output.= "} # end package $pack\n1;\n";
    return $output;
}

sub perlstr { Data::Dumper->new([''.shift])
    ->Terse(1)->Indent(0)->Useqq(1)->Dump }
```

Input File:

```
\perlExec{
    use warnings; use strict;
    print "Hello, World\n";
    my $v = [ 1, 2 ];
    my $w = [ 3, 4 ];
    sub list ($) {
        my $pdl = shift;
        return join ',', @$pdl;
    }
}
The vector [ \perlValue{ list $v } ]
plus the vector [ \perlValue{ list $w } ]
makes [ \perlValue{ my $s = [@$v + @$w]; list $s } ].
```

Output:

```
>>>>> Generated Code:
{ package Generated1_input_txt;
no warnings; no strict;
#line 1 "Generated1_input_txt"

    use warnings; use strict;
    print "Hello, World\n";
    my $v = [ 1, 2 ];
    my $w = [ 3, 4 ];
    sub list ($) {
        my $pdl = shift;
        return join ',', @$pdl;
    }
;
print "\nThe vector [ ";
print do {  list $v ; };
print " ]\nplus the vector [ ";
print do {  list $w ; };
print " ]\nmakes [ ";
print do {  my $s = [@$v + @$w]; list $s ; };
print " ].\n";
} # end package Generated1_input_txt
1;
<<<<<
>>>>> Output:
Hello, World

The vector [ 1,2 ]
plus the vector [ 3,4 ]
makes [ 4 ].
<<<<<
```

*Update:* As suggested by @HåkonHægland in the comments, it's possible to use [`PPR`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPR) to parse out the blocks. The only changes needed are to replace `use Regexp::Common qw/balanced/;` by `use PPR;` and in the regex replace `(?<code> $RE{balanced}{-parens=>'{}'} )` by `(?<code> (?&PerlBlock) ) $PPR::GRAMMAR` - then the parser will handle a case like `print "Hello, World }\n";` too!

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put into this and for mentioning the Template toolkit, which in a way belongs here, too. However, when I first came accross the toolkit a while ago, I had the impression that the perl code and the template text would be too far apart for the editor to easily author the document. This is why I did not go that route in the end. I think the Eval::WithLexicals exactly matches my question, and thus I have accepted that answer.

Comment: Nice example! Do you think [PPR](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPR) could be used here? That is: to improve the robustness of the Perl parser..

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach: Parse the template file twice. On first parse, write Perl statements from the template to a temp file, for example `/tmp/MyTemplate.pm`, add some header code to this file such as to make it a valid Perl module. Also use a sequential numbering into package variables for `\perlValue` statements, i.e. translate the first `\perlValue{ list $v }` into for example: `our $perl_value1 = list $v;`, the next `\perlValue{ list $w }` becomes `our $perl_value2 = list $w;` and so on..

Then require the module: `require "/tmp/MyTmplate.pm";` Then parse the template a second time, extracting the correct values corresponding to Perl code in the template from the symbol table of `MyTemplate`. For example to get the value of `\perlValue{ list $v }` use `$MyTemplate::perl_value1` and so on..